# Can someone explain this line of Batch to me?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
for /F %%i in ('net view') do copy /Y %0 "%%ic$documents and settingsall usersstart menuprogramsstartup"
```

Can someone explain this line of Batch to me?

Comment: Have you tried google it? http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

Comment: The batch file is copying itself to each computer the net view command finds. Kind of a self propigating worm.

Comment: "%%ic$documents and settingsall usersstart menuprogramsstartup" what is this line referencing? What directory?

Comment: @HarryAllen, if you add `echo ` before `copy` like `echo copy .....` then you will see that `%%i` expands to a network path. However I think your command misses path separators ```\```.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'll give that a try -- I think you may be right. I was pretty confused on it

Comment: And try `for /F %%i in ('net view^|find "\\"') do ...` to throw away all header and footer lines from `net view` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type `FOR /?` at the command prompt, you get this:

> FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]
>
> %variable   Specifies a single letter replaceable parameter.   (set) 
>   Specifies a set of one or more files.  Wildcards may be used.
>   command    Specifies the command to carry out for each file.
>   command-parameters
>                Specifies parameters or switches for the specified command.
>
> To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
>   of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different
>   from %I.

Then below you see this:

> FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('command') DO command [command-parameters]

This means that `FOR /F` allows you to execute a command for a file set. Here in your OP specifically, the optional `"options"` is not used.

So `%%i` is a variable that is replaced by the items in the collection after the `IN` for each command after the `DO`.

`('net view')` executes the command `net view`. This basically lists all the computers in the network. You can run it at the command prompt and see.

`c$` is the default share for the C: drive on a Windows computer.

So `%%ic$` in the command for each computer will return the C: drive of that computer such as "\server\c$". (Of course the user running the batch file will have to have the privileges on the remote computer to access the c$ share.)

`%0` means the the current file (the batch file that is executing). Just put `ECHO %0` in a batch file and run it and you will see.

After the `do` comes the command you want to execute for each file.

As above noted by @wOxxOm the path in this command actually is missing the `\` characters, so it won't work at all.

With this probably already figured out that this command:

- executes the `net view` command and gets the list of all computers visible on the network
- and copies the current batch file that is being executed to the folder on the C: drive on that computer

(Except that it won't do it with the `\`s missing from the path.)